# Best performances to find a value in a DataTable ? For ? Linq ? Other?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, datatable

I have a big txt file loaded in a DataTable on a c# programm.

I need to search severasl values in this dataTable.

For the moment i use a simple For loop, and it's veery long !
I really need to gain time.

Is there a better way to perform this ? Using Linq ? or another method ?

Here is a basic sample of my code :

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTables[0].Rows) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= DataTables[1].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        if ((DataTables[1].Rows[i]["PRODUCT_CODE"].ToString().Trim() == row["PRODUCT_CODE"].ToString().Trim())
        {
            // Do Some Stuff
            // When the value is found, don't break the for...continue because there is severals "PRODUCT_CODE", not once.
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is how is your data structured? Can you restructure it better in order to search more efficiently? Arguing about whether to use linq or for loop is irrelevant.

Comment: if you want to search for specific value only then for loop is better after found value , break the loop. Hope it will helpful for you

Comment: DataTable.Select and it is not linq but a native method of the class.Why don't you post the code that executes your search now? This is necessary to understand what can be optimized

Comment: If you want to know which horse is the fastest... race them

Comment: Hello, i edited my code !  thanks :)

Comment: If performance is your goal, linq will _not_ be the answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
HashSet<string> dt0 = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in DataTables[0].Rows) 
    dt0.Add(row["PRODUCT_CODE"].ToString().Trim());
for (int i = 0; i <= DataTables[1].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if ( dt0.Contains(DataTables[1].Rows[i]["PRODUCT_CODE"].ToString().Trim() == row["PRODUCT_CODE"].ToString().Trim())
    {
        // Do Some Stuff
        // When the value is found, don't break the for...continue because there is severals "PRODUCT_CODE", not once.
    } 
}
```

Just went from O(n^m) to O(n+m)

If you need the whole row then Dictionary rather then HashSet

```
Dictionary<String, DataRow> dt0 = new Dictionary<String, DataRow>();
```

You should use the HashSet / Dictionary for the the larger.

I would give you more but you had the insolence to ask me if I thought this would be faster.

Why are you using DataTables in the first place?

Comment: Because i display it in a datagridview, more easy to debug as visual ! Yeah, i need the whole row. Do you think it will be really faster ?

Comment: No I just spent my time on a wild guess.   And totally made the from O(n^m) to O(n+m).  Your loop is *easy*.   Do you want speed or easy?   Because DataTable is not the fastest.

Comment: Sorry Paparazzi, i wouldn't be insolent. I'm really sorry and i appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello,i thnk i cannot use your method because i can hever severals time the same PRODUCT_CODE, so, it's not a unique key. I thin k i have too use a for loop as parralel.

Comment: I think there is a lot of stuff you cannot use.  In another comment you said it was unique in one.  You could use Dictionary(string, List(DataRows))  but I am tired of trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

A short example use more as one core

```
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), row =>
{
    if (i["value1"].ToString() == "test")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i["value1"]);
    }
});
```

**Other Solution**

Compare Keys is very fast

```
Dictionary<string, Product> file1 = new Dictionary<string, Product>();
Dictionary<string, Product> file2 = new Dictionary<string, Product>();

//Add ProductCode in key

var product = new Product();
product.Code = "EAN1202";
product.Manufacturer = "Company";
product.Name = "Test";
product.Price = 12.05;

file1.Add(product.Code, product);

//One thread
foreach (var item in file1)
{
   if (file2.ContainsKey(item.Key))
   {
      // Do Some Stuff
   }
}

//Multi thread
Parallel.ForEach(file1, item =>
{
   if (file2.ContainsKey(item.Key))
   {
      // Do Some Stuff
   }
});
```

Product Class

```
public class Product
{
    public string Code;
    public string Manufacturer;
    public string Name;
    public double Price;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Is your code suitable with two dataTable ? I edited my questions with my code, if you need to understand. Thanks again :)

Comment: Another question...on my "file2". Product code is not the primary key. There is severals the same Product code. And i need to iterate as many as there as. WIll be this ok with your code ?

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be a bit better if we knew what you were doing in the loop, but this should work:

```
var dt1=DataTables[0].Rows.AsEnumerable();
var dt2=DataTables[1].Rows.AsEnumerable();
var results=dt1.Join(
  dt2,
  d1=>d1.Field<string>("PRODUCT_CODE").Trim(),
  d2=>d2.Field<string>("PRODUCT_CODE").Trim(),
  (d1,d2)=>new {d1,d2});
foreach(var row in results)
{
  // Do stuff with row.d1/row.d2
}
```

If for example, your data tables are created from a SQL source, it would be better to use join on that instead, which will allow the SQL server to do the joining instead of doing it client-side.  Also, not using datatables, and using a POCO class would improve your performance some as well as you won't need to box/unbox the product code during the join.

Comment: It'll be faster than what he has, but not as fast as using a hashset like you did (I think).  I don't believe LINQ will use hashsets internally when doing the join, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Of course it'll depend a lot of the shape of the data as well.  If dt1 has 1-3 records, while dt2 has (m|b)illions, the hashset won't help much unless it's reversed.

Comment: He is reading a text file and it he does not seems to be actually trying any of the proposed answers.

Comment: Ooops, I missed the text file part.  Probably would be better if he processed the file as he's reading it rather than loading it into a datatable.

Comment: @RobertMcKee LINQ actually does use internal lightweight hash sets when doing joins. I would have been really surprised if it doesn't :)